# SQLAlchemy NoReferencedTableError but I have all the relationships and tables declared

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm

I have the following code for a Task Manager app.

```
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, MetaData, String, DateTime, Table, text, Enum
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from .database import Base


metadata = MetaData()


#association table for group members
user_group_members = Table(
    "user_group_members",
    metadata,
    Column("user_group_id", Integer, ForeignKey("user_groups.id"), primary_key=True), # group
    Column("user_id", Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"), primary_key=True), # user
    Column("role", String, nullable=False),  # role
)

# Association table for users groups and tasks groups
user_group_tasks_groups = Table(
    "user_group_tasks_groups",
    metadata,
    Column("user_group_id", Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"), primary_key=True), # users group
    Column("task_group_id", Integer, ForeignKey("task_groups.id"), primary_key=True), # tasks group
    Column("role", String, nullable=False)
)


# Main tables: Users and tasks
class UsersTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    username = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    user_creation = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False, server_default=text("now()"))
    valid_email = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, server_default=text("FALSE"))  # email validation # user_state -> True: Active, False: Inactive (For irreversible user deletion)
    user_state = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, server_default=text("TRUE"))

    groups = relationship("UserGroupsTable", secondary=user_group_members, back_populates="members")
    tasks = relationship("TasksTable", back_populates="users")


class TasksTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tasks"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False)
    description = Column(String, nullable=True)
    content = Column(String, nullable=True)
    task_group_id = Column(String, nullable=True)
    task_creation = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False, server_default=text("now()"))
    task_owner = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=False)

    users = relationship("UsersTable", back_populates="tasks")


# Groups: Tasks groups and users groups
class UserGroupsTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_groups"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    user_group_name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    description = Column(String, nullable=False)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=False)

    members = relationship("UsersTable", secondary=user_group_members, back_populates="groups")
    group_owner = relationship("UsersTable", back_populates="owned_groups", foreign_keys=[owner_id])
    tasks_groups = relationship("TaskGroupsTable", secondary=user_group_tasks_groups)


class TaskGroupsTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "task_groups"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    task_group_name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    description = Column(String, nullable=False) 
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=False)

    group_owner = relationship("UsersTable", back_populates="users", foreign_keys=[owner_id])
    user_groups = relationship("UserGroupsTable", secondary=user_group_members)
```

For some reason, I cannot run the program because of the following error.

```
raise exc.NoReferencedTableError(
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'user_group_members.user_group_id' could not find table 'user_groups' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

I tried to move the classes around, change the names of the tables, and even the way I try to associate the tables by their actual name (the `__tablename__` property) or by the class name.

I think the issue is related with the parameters `secondary` and `back_populate` in the relationship property defined in all the classes, but after hours of trying, I cannot find where is the mistake. If someone can even explain better those properties and how to use it, maybe I can find a way to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

## Tables and Columbus should be created before being used

You should create `users_group` before adding its id in `user_group_members`

Here, you try to use `users_group_id` before having created the users_group itself.

### Solution

- Put the creation of the table `users_group` before `user_group_members`

I think there is the same problem with `user.id` in `user_group_members`

You should take care of creating tables in the good order.

### Other problems

In `user_group_tasks_groups` you do a reference to user.id in the  `user_group_id` Column, maybe you want to use `user_groups.id` ?